# Current Prices for Cryptocurrencies

Tags: cryptocurrency

Is there a way to actively download the current price for cryptocurrencies into a Google spreadsheet?  Google allows for downloading stock prices.  Is there a similar formula for downloading cryptocurrency prices?

Answer (score 0):

Cryptosheets has data that can be pulled into Excel, and there are also Chainlink APIs and contracts that can be used in Solidity code. Just take a look at the Chainlink documentation. I believe Chainlink is more focused on Ethereum and layer 2 Ethereum tokens, however, and I have heard from some users that Cryptosheet's functionality has faced some challenges.